# split rows of an R data frame into a list of lists by splitting on an element

Tags: r, dataframe, list, split

I have a data frame something like this

```
data <- data.frame(x1 = c("10",20,50,10,90,30,40),  
                   x2 = c("50",20,10,80,-99,100,60), 
                   x3 = c("50",20,-99,80,90,100,60), 
                   x4 = c("50",20,10,80,90,100,60), 
                   x5 = c("0",10,30,50,70,40,80))     

#  print the dataframe 
data
```

I'd like to split it into a list of lists by splitting on an element eg -99. That number, -99, occurs n rows 2 nd 3 of the 5 row data frame so I'd want a list of 5 elements with the 2nd and 3rd element being a list of 2 vectors - the elements before and after -99
ie the 3rd element of the list would be this (derived from the 3rd elements of x1-x5 with a -99 value of x3 being the splitting value)

```
list(list(c(50,10)),c(10,30))
```

I know I made the elements in the data frame character as I thought that might help
many thanks in advance

Comment: Is that the complete output you want? Only from the 3rd row? Or you want to split every row? Or you want to split only rows that have a `-99` in them?

Comment: What happens if there is more than one `-99` in a row? Multiple splits? Or ignore the 2nd one? Or something else?

Comment: sorry for delay, Gregor, yes I'd want to split every row with a -99 in it thanks. and if there are multiple -99s I'd like multiple splits so if there are 2 -99s I'd want 3 lists. thanks for all your help. Your code worked really well an after a bit of thought I understood how it worked. I think it will do all the things I want (I'll check). thanks again

Comment: Yes, it should do all those things :)

Comment: its perfect thanks again Gregor - I realised I also needed it to ignore initial -99s in a row eg x1 = c(-99,20,50,10,90,30,40) is 1 sub-list (ie don't want an initial empty list) and it seems to do that too, fab :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my best guess given the inconsistencies in the question (7-row data frame called a "5 row data frame").

```
split_at_val = function(x, val) {
  s = x == val
  count = cumsum(s)
  unname(split(x[!s], count[!s]))
}

apply(data, 1, split_at_val, val = -99)
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
#   x1   x2   x3   x4   x5 
# "10" "50" "50" "50"  "0" 
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
#   x1   x2   x3   x4   x5 
# "20" "20" "20" "20" "10" 
# 
# 
# [[3]]
# [[3]][[1]]
#   x1   x2 
# "50" "10" 
# 
# [[3]][[2]]
#   x4   x5 
# "10" "30" 
# 
# 
# [[4]]
# [[4]][[1]]
#   x1   x2   x3   x4   x5 
# "10" "80" "80" "80" "50" 
# 
# 
# [[5]]
# [[5]][[1]]
#   x1 
# "90" 
# 
# [[5]][[2]]
#   x3   x4   x5 
# "90" "90" "70" 
# 
# 
# [[6]]
# [[6]][[1]]
#    x1    x2    x3    x4    x5 
#  "30" "100" "100" "100"  "40" 
# 
# 
# [[7]]
# [[7]][[1]]
#   x1   x2   x3   x4   x5 
# "40" "60" "60" "60" "80"
```

Comment: thanks Gregor, that works perfectly (and apologies you are right I meant 7 row - got my rows and columsn confused)